# Display the JSON response received using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having some problem to displaying the response getting from the below given code. Please help me to display the response on my page that I am getting from this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    $('#m_p_advc').change(function () {
        var sup = $('#m_p_advc').val();
        $('#result').html(sup);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../hcshimla/newfiling/ajaxfunction.php',
            data: {gadvcd: sup, flag: 'ADV'},
            success: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response.first);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the screenshot of data that I am receiving through this code:

[image: Screenshot of the response I am getting]

In this response (data) I want to split every bit of information seperating with "~" (sign) and display them on different textboxes on the form.

Comment: once you get the response, split your data with " ~ " sign. This will give you an array. Now to this array loop it in your HTML text boxes.  This will be helpful if you provide your HTML as well.

Comment: why don't you format php response in json format? At the moment response is not `dataType: "json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your response you got,split them with ~ and if you want to display the splitted values on different textboxes means loop them inorder to place the value with the respective text boxes.. Here is the sample code for that.. Not sure whether your looking for this kind of an output..

Sample Html:

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox0"  />
<input type="text" id="TextBox1"  />
<input type="text" id="TextBox2"  />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../hcshimla/newfiling/ajaxfunction.php',
        data: {gadvcd: sup, flag: 'ADV'},
        success: function (response) {

            var arr = response.split("~");

            for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
            {
                $('#TextBox' + i + '').val(arr[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error displaying as an alert message. The error is "[object Object]". What was wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
$('#m_p_advc').change(function(){
var sup = $('#m_p_advc').val();
$('#result').html(sup);
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: 'GET',
  url: '../hcshimla/newfiling/ajaxfunction.php',
  data: {  gadvcd: sup,  flag: 'ADV' },
  success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var responseData = response.split("~"); //ResponseData is an array

         $.each(responseData, function(i, v){
               // Do your menupulation.
          });
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
success: function(response) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    $('#result').html(obj.first);
}
```

Comment: response is not straight json

Comment: You set your dataType to 'json' so that is what ajax is expecting to receive back. Try omitting the datatype and see if the default will do the job.

Comment: response is html, just a string

Comment: Exactly. So you need to change the dataType to "html" or omit the option completely and it should default to html. Read the dataType option on [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)